# Export multiple SVG files generated with Inkscape to multiple PDF files

Tags: svg, pdf, export, software-recommendation

I have around 150 SVG files created in Inkscape. Is there is a utility that can export all of these to multiple PDF or PNG files?

Exporting individually is too time consuming, so I was wondering if I could do it in a batch with some utility/software.

Windows preferred.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some other options tools to convert to/from SVG from the [Inkscape Wiki](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/Tools):

- [svg2pdf](http://cairographics.org/)
- [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)
- [ConversionSVG](https://sourceforge.net/projects/conversionsvg/)

Comment: I started using ConversionSVG. Amazing, It was lightweight. No pretence, just what I was looking for. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 10):

For people who landed here from a google search because this question references *Inkscape* <s>but isn't tagged with Windows,</s> here's a complete howto for Linux (this assumes you have Inkscape installed on your system - tested on Ubunut 14.04 with Inkscape 0.91).

Create a file in the directory where you want to convert your SVG*s* to PDF*s*. (I used `gedit` below but you might as well replace it the text editor of your choice)

```
gedit convertSVGtoPDF.sh
```

Paste the following code inside

```bash
#!/bin/bash
mkdir export_dir
for file in *.svg; do
    filename=$(basename "$file")
    inkscape "$file" --export-type=pdf --export-area-drawing --export-dpi=1200 -o "export_dir/${filename%.svg}.pdf"
done
```

Save the file.

> Note: Changes you can make to the script above.
>
> `--export-type` can be one of: [svg,png,ps,eps,pdf,emf,wmf,xaml]
>
> `--export-dpi` is just the dots per inch number you want on the new file
>
> `--export-area-drawing` will export only the drawing. If you want the page instead, use `--export-area-page`
>
> For older versions of Inkscape,
> before 1.2, the `-o` flag should be replaced by `-A`.

Now make this script executable

```
chmod +x convertSVGtoPDF.sh
```

And execute it inside your directory containing the SVG*s*

```
./convertSVGtoPDF.sh
```

This will create a new folder called `export_dir` where you can find your PDFs with embedded fonts.

Happy Inkscaping!

Comment: Hi A__, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you have any questions, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Comment: This would also be possible on Windows using a batch script of powershell, although it is worth mentioning [this minor quirk](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/FAQ#I.27m_on_Windows.2C_and_command_line_parameters_don.27t_seem_to_work.21) about the Inkscape command line under Windows.

Comment: This worked  for me except I had to remove `$PWD/`. It didn't work because there were spaces in my directory path.

Comment: I used this to convert PDF to SVG using pdf2svg. Excellent answer!

Comment: Tested on Ubuntu 16.04. Great!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this using Inkscape's [command line interface](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/CommandLine.html) (`inkscape --without-gui --export-pdf=myfile.pdf myfile.svg`), and then use a batch file, shell script, or build tool (such as Make, Rake, or Grunt) to run that automatically on a whole list of files.

Answer (score 3):

After looking multiple sites I've found a simple way using only one command line.

I've never used command line before, but after some experimentation I've came with the following solution:

```bash
for /f "tokens=1* delims=." %i in ('dir /b *.svg') do "C:\Program Files\Inkscape\inkscape.exe" --without-gui --file="%i.svg" --export-emf="%i.emf"
```

Breaking it down:

```bash
for
```

for is a command to perform an action to multiple files. It's structure is something like: for "files in a certain condition" do "especific command"

```bash
/f "tokens=1* delims=." %i in ('dir /b *.svg')
```

This is the "condition". In my case, I'm looking for all SVG files, but of course it works with others formats. All this "fancy" code does is store the file name, before the  extention, in the variable "%i". This will be usefull in the comand.

```bash
do
```

That is what you will perform in all the files.

```bash
"C:\Program Files\Inkscape\inkscape.exe" --without-gui --file="%i.svg" --export-emf="%i.emf"
```

This is the same command Marnen Laibow-Koser used above. I'm a newbie, i don't know how you use just "inkscape", so i've putted all the way to the .exe.

The last part is where we use the variable to instruct the program to wich file it should pick and how export.

Again, I'm exporting SVG to EMF, but just change it to what you want. Here is why the variable are so important. So you can keep the same name, just changing the extention.

Don't forget to use the quotes, since your files can have some space in it's name.

Of course you also need to be in the folder where your files are. If your are also a newbie do this:

```bash
C:\
```

It will put you in the correct drive.

```bash
CD "path"
```

It will take you to the specific folder. You can use the windows explorer and click with right button and copy the path as text.

That's it. I'm newbie, soo it might be someway more efective to do it, but this will work.

Last tip: If you are working with a lot of files, you can use CTRL + C to stop the command line if it's not working how it should, and try again.

Answer (score 0):

[This link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/inkscapebatch/) seems to have what you want: Batch export from inkscape in windows.

Comment: The link is unfortunately dead, and it seems like InkscapeBatch was abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have consecutive file names.

Assuming you are using macOS.

```sh
INDIR='3. SVGs/svgs-front'
OUTDIR='4. Individual PDFs/pdfs-front'
seq 1 100 | while read row; do
  echo Processing $row
  /Applications/Inkscape.app/Contents/MacOS/inkscape -o $OUTDIR/$row.pdf --without-gui $INDIR/$row.svg 
done
```

Answer (score -2):

For me the best way to do it is [zamzar.com](http://www.zamzar.com)
which is a free online file conversion site.  It allows user to convert files without downloading a software tool, and supports over 1,000 different conversion types.

Comment: Hello user17598, welcome to GDSE and thank you for your contribution. Could you please tell us a bit more about what we can find at your link? We'd like your post to be useful to future visitors, even in the case your link breaks. Thanks and enjoy your stay!